# C# WinForms MetroUI ComboBox set SelectedIndex not working

Tags: winforms, combobox, microsoft-metro, selectedindex

I'm using WinForms MetroUI controls https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui.

Metro ComboBox control has issue with selecting combo box item using:

```
comboBox.selectedIndex = 0;
```

If I switch to old Form ComboBox control, above code work.

Does anyone succeed in setting SelectedIndex using Metro ComboBox?

Thanks in advance,

Josip

Answer (score 0):

I made SelectedIndex selection to work by reloading MetroFramework.dll and by replacing combo box control.

For some reason it works now.

This can be mark done!